# Как повысить посещаемость сайта?

Tags: seo

Как повысить посещаемость сайта? Как выбрать аудиторию? В каком виде подавать инфу?

Comment: моя думать это - не очень программерский вопрос.

Comment: Никто не говорит, что это программерский вопрос!

Answer (score 2):

Ну дык для этого есть [методы раскрутки сайта](http://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B+%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest), которые делятся на 3 категории:

- черные методы раскрутки сайта,
- белые методы раскрутки сайта,
- контекстная и баннерная реклама.

Раскрутка сайта - это, во-первых, психология, во-вторых, это время и ацкий труд, над раскруткой сайта нужно долбаться и еще раз долбаться! У любого сайта будет своя аудитория, если сайт не пустой. Для того чтобы сайт не был пустой, нужно писать хотя бы 3-5 статеек в неделю. К примеру, я игнорирую сайты вообще обо всем, и типа варез, *уярез и прочие быдлосайты. Поэтому прежде всего сайт должен, по крайне мере, для освоения опыта иметь узконаправленную тематику... Уникальность контента, важность контента, ссылочная масса, умная внутренняя перелинковка, хорошие анкоры и т.п. и т.д.

Основную инфу можно прочесть по предложенным мной ссылкам и выбрать для себя подходящий! Bот еще один линк, где есть интересные идеи от автора - [eurows.org](http://eurows.org/).

Comment: Добавил в закладки eurows

Comment: Советую воспользоваться www.google.com/alerts добавить запрос типа - "продвижение сайта" и гугл будет сам слать новую инфу на почту с сылкой на статью или новость! Короче говоря постоянный источник только нужной инфы, а главное новой!

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос очень широкий и емкий.

Очень многое зависит от типа того ресурса, который вы планируете продвигать. Сейчас реально имеют значение два вида продвижения: в поиске и в сетях.

- Продвижение в поиске существенно для открытых информационных ресурсов: форумов, блогов, новостей, энциклопедий и т.п. При этом залогом успеха является содержимое сайта - полнота и уникальность предлагаемой посетителю информации. Обычно достаточно создать на ресурсе какое-то критическое количество интересной посетителям информации. Например, если ресурс посвящено космонавтике, выбрать самые популярные поисковые запросы и освещать их на ресурсе.
- Продвижение в сетях существенно для не информационных ресурсов, магазинов, служб, и т.п. В этом случае залогом успеха является качество и удобство работы с сайтом. Потому что люди начинают рекомендовать его друг другу. Скажем для сайта-витрины, который занимается продажей товара, главное - это удобство работы с ним и цены на продаваемые товары.

Практически всегда в самом начале необходима платная реклама: либо имиджевая, либо прямая.